# Sonar build breaker for travis

Tags: cloud, travis-ci, sonarqube-web

I'm working on a  continous integration cloud enviroment, using travis ci for server and sonarqube.com for static analysis. I wondering if there is a plugin/configuration for break the build process when some sonar threshold is triggered (like the build braeker plugin for the sonar server version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used a maven plugin for cobertura analisys, the cobertura plugin, wich take the configuration from the pom file, and I included into CI pipeline configured in the travis configuration file (travis.yml). The script result was:

```
mvn clean cobertura:check sonar:sonar tomcat7:redeploy
```

The sonar plataform was used only for static analysis but not for cobertura.
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

looks like the sonar qube community has a plugin: https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker/

Comment: Yes, but that plugin is for the installable version of sonar. I'm using the cloud version. Thanks for the answer.